# How to retrieve the latest version of all docker images using AQL

Tags: artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

I'm trying to figure it out how to retrieve the latest version of each image stored in the Docker repo using AQL. The following code gives me all the versions but I couldn't find a way to get only the latest one for each asset.

```
curl -u "username:password" -i -X POST <host>/artifactory/api/search/aql  -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -d '
    items.find(
        {
            "repo":{"$eq":"my-docker-repo"},
            "$or":[
                {"path": { "$match" : "application/*" }},
                {"path": { "$match" : "service/*" }}
            ]
        }
    ).include("repo", "path", "name", "created").sort({"$desc" : ["path","created"]})'
```

Thanks!
Andre

Answer (score 0):

The brainiacs over at R&D created a cool util that also serves the purpose your'e looking to achieve, you can get it [here](https://github.com/jfrog/docker-remote-util).  You can also check the sources for the exact AQL query it runs if you want to implement something similar for your own usecase.